# Render to BufferedImage in Java3D

Tags: java, 3d, bufferedimage, java-3d

Is there a simple way of rendering to a `BufferedImage` in Java3D?

I know you can [extend `Canvas3D`](http://java3d.j3d.org/faq/capturing.html), but it seems cumbersome if I just want to render directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be some examples showing how to do this such as [`PrintCanvas3D.java`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/3D/PrintCanvas3D.htm) and [`OffScreenTest.java`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/3D/OffScreenTest.htm), both giving examples of off-screen rendering.